# Invent a linear mapping that transforms the function

Tags: linear-algebra

> Create a linear mapping called $F :R^2 \to R^2$ such that it transforms the ellipse $y^2 + 2xy + 3x^2 = 4$ into the circle $u^2 + v^2 = 2$.

So we must have $(u, v) = F(x, y)$

How can I "approach" this say? This is a bit difficult to go through with.

I see that the sum of squares must $2$, but not sure how to approach?

Answer (score 3):

Without using diagonalization or eigenvectors, by completing the squares
\begin{align}
  y^2+2xy+3x^2 &= 4 \\
  (y+x)^2+2x^2 &= 4 \\
  \left( \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2+x^2 &=2 \\
  u &= \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}} \\
  v &= x
\end{align}